# I cannot get the value of CHtml::dropDownList with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I am new to PHP and Javascript and I have an issue with the following problem. Here is my html/php:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('contact_list','',
                  (array)Driver::contactDropList( Driver::getUserId())
                  ,array(
                  'class'=>"contact_list chosen"
                  ))?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am trying to reset this field when a button Cancel is clicked. By reset I mean to make it with value Select from contacts (it is the first option in the dropdown). Here is and my Javascript code, which is not working properly. It only closes the form, but without refresh of the page the dropdown value is there and it is not changed to the default one:

```
        $( document ).on( "click", ".close-modal", function() {     
            var elements = $('.contact_list');
            elements.select = 'Select from contacts';
            var id=$(this).data("id");
            $(id).modal('hide');
        });
```

I also tried to reset the whole form with `$("#frm").reset();` method, but there was no desired result, too.

[image: This is the default value, which I want to appear every time when the form is open:]

Now, it is appearing the previous value, which the user have chosen.

[image: first]

[image: second]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.contact_list option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Try this

You can also try the following code:

```
$(".contact_list").prop("selectedIndex",0);
```

Note: This option will select the first option of dropdown. Make sure to make "Select your contact" first option

Comment: It is my first option, but unfortunately, neither of your suggestions work. Maybe I am missing something. Here is my code: 
 var id=$(this).data("id");
 $(id).modal('hide');
$('.contact_list option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected"); (OR $(".contact_list").prop("selectedIndex",0);)

Comment: Right click on dropdown, Select inspect element, and send me screenshot of generated dropdown and its children

Comment: I have added two photos in my original question as first and second

Comment: $('.chosen-single span').html("Select from contacts");
$('.result-selected').removeClass("result-selected");
$('li[data-option-array-index=0]').addClass("result-selected");

Comment: Try this code. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the pre-selected value of `$(.contact_list)` then first you need to set a variable of pre-selected value:

```
var contactVal = $('.contact_list').find(":selected").val();
```

Now after `$(id).modal('hide');` you set the pre-selected value:

```
$('.contact_list option[value=contactVal]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: `var contactVal = $('.contact_list').find(":selected").val();` is returning undefined and does not fixed the problem. :(

Comment: Is this pre selected form or after close modal you just want to show **"Select from contacts"** ? If this is not pre-selected then `var contactVal = $('.contact_list').val();` will solve the issue.

Comment: When you firstly open the form you see the default value which is the first one (I upload an image in my original question). After that you choose an option from the dropdown (for example - Alexander), then you click Cancel and when you try to open the form one more time Alexander is still there, instead of Select from contacts.

Comment: Understood. Ok I think after  `$( document ).on( "click", ".close-modal", function() { ` this line you should add `$('.contact_list option:selected').attr("selected",null);` I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: I really appreciate your desire and time to help me, but it is still does not work. When I alert this `$('.contact_list option:selected')`, it is returning undefined, if this can clear it a bit.

Comment: Sir, I am extremely sorry for the last comment. The updated code should put inside `start-modal` not `close-modal`. So the code should be `$( document ).on( "click", ".start-modal", function() {` after this line please add `$('.contact_list option:selected').attr("selected",null);`. If you don't have this block then create and put that code inside the block. Please accept my wrong information. I am extremely sorry for that.

Comment: There is no problem, I tried this one too, but there is no result.